# Git Visual Studio 2015 Automatic commit upon successful build

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2015

I would like to automate my commits on Visual studio. However, I do not want to commit every time the files change. I want to only commit upon successful builds. So my code is always "buildable".

The main reason, I tend to forget to commit in between big changes and I always end up committing before and after adding features.

Comment: I think  you can put "Post Build" commands into VS.  I have always pointed those to a BAT file which then would do what i needed to do since the internal commandset of VS was limited.  So, you could create a saveViaGit.bat file, and then call it using $(ProjectPath)

Comment: @user2174714 Thanks, will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: This question keeps on getting upvoted, yet no full answer. I still haven't figured out how to actually do it.

Comment: please elaborate on you request

Comment: @user2174714-1: Are you kidding me? A working solution would be a start...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that setting the following under PostBuild event on the project might work:

```
git commit -am "Succesful build at $(date -u +'%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')"
```